# slider recalculate window width when resizing

Tags: jquery, resize, slider

I have build a slider with testimonies that slides automatically. When loading the webpage for the first time it calculates the width of the window and use this value to move throughout the blocks of text, but when I resize the window it maintains the previous values and everything is disbalanced.

The main problem is that the value of the slider container and the slides are percentual, so trying `$(window).resize(function(){$slides.width(width)});` it's useless.

HTML

```
<div class="testimonial-container">
            <div class="testimonials">
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="testimonials">
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="testimonials">
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="testimonials">
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.testimonial-container{
    width: 400%;
}
.testimonials{
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(function(){
        //configuration
        var width=$(window).width();
        var animationSpeed = 1200;
        var pause = 3000;
        var currentSlide = 1;
        var interval;
        //cache DOM
        var $slider = $('#testimonial');
        var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.testimonial-container');
        var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.testimonials');

        function startSlider(){
            interval = setInterval(function(){
                $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left':'-='+width},animationSpeed,"easeOutQuart", function(){
                    currentSlide++;
                    if(currentSlide === $slides.length){
                        currentSlide = 1;
                        $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
                        addActive();
                    }
                });
            }, pause);
        }
        startSlider();
});
```

Comment: have you tried reinitiating the slider on widow.resize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle.

**EDIT: Use JSFiddle Link below for testing the resize :-)**

I recalculate the width on resize, stop the slider, reset the margin and then run the slider again:

```js
$(function(){
        //configuration
        var width=$(window).width();
        var animationSpeed = 1200;
        var pause = 3000;
        var currentSlide = 1;
        var interval;
        //cache DOM
        var $slideContainer = $('.testimonial-container');
        var $slides = $slideContainer.find('.testimonials');

        function startSlider(){
            interval = setInterval(function(){
                $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left':'-='+width},animationSpeed, function(){
                    currentSlide++;
                    if(currentSlide === $slides.length){
                        currentSlide = 1;
                        $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
                    }
                });
            }, pause);
        }
        startSlider();
        
        $(window).on('resize', function(){
         clearInterval(interval);
         width=$(window).width();
            $slideContainer.css('marginLeft', '0');
            startSlider();
        });
});
```

```css
html, body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.testimonial-container{
    width: 400%;
}
.testimonials{
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testimonial-container">
            <div class="testimonials">
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="testimonials">
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="testimonials">
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="testimonials">
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
```

**INFO: Here is the JSFiddle for resizing testing:** https://jsfiddle.net/ks50njnz/1/